# Matlab guide GUI toogle/push button?

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have been working on a matlab GUI for a while now and have finally gotten it do what I want now I am just working on making a bit cleaner and user friendly. I have 5 panels and have stacked them all on top of each other and have added 5 push buttons on top of the panel. Is there a way to be able to bring a panel to the front by pressing on the push button?

```
function togglebutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
```

This is my call back for the push button. Is there anything i can add to make a panel come to the front by clicking on it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of tools/examples for creating tabbed panels that have been submitted to the [MathWorks File Exchange](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&term=tab%20panel). Any one of them would probably do what you want. However, you can also do it yourself pretty easily with a [`uibuttongroup`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uibuttongroup.html). Here's a simple example for a tabbed panel design:

```
function tab_panel

  hFigure = figure('Units', 'pixels', 'Position', [200 200 320 320]);

  hPanel1 = uipanel(hFigure, 'Units', 'pixels', 'Position', [10 10 300 270], ...
                    'BackgroundColor', 'r');
  hPanel2 = uipanel(hFigure, 'Units', 'pixels', 'Position', [10 10 300 270], ...
                    'BackgroundColor', 'g', 'Visible', 'off');
  hPanel3 = uipanel(hFigure, 'Units', 'pixels', 'Position', [10 10 300 270], ...
                    'BackgroundColor', 'b', 'Visible', 'off');

  hGroup = uibuttongroup(hFigure, 'Units', 'pixels', 'Position', [10 280 300 30], ...
                         'BorderType', 'none', 'SelectionChangedFcn', @switch_panel);
  hButton1 = uicontrol(hGroup, 'Style', 'toggle', 'Position', [0 0 40 30], ...
                       'String', 'Red');
  hButton2 = uicontrol(hGroup, 'Style', 'toggle', 'Position', [40 0 40 30], ...
                       'String', 'Green');
  hButton3 = uicontrol(hGroup, 'Style', 'toggle', 'Position', [80 0 40 30], ...
                       'String', 'Blue');

  function switch_panel(~, eventData)  % Nested callback function
    switch eventData.NewValue
      case hButton1
        set(hPanel1, 'Visible', 'on');
        set([hPanel2 hPanel3], 'Visible', 'off');
      case hButton2
        set(hPanel2, 'Visible', 'on');
        set([hPanel1 hPanel3], 'Visible', 'off');
      case hButton3
        set(hPanel3, 'Visible', 'on');
        set([hPanel1 hPanel2], 'Visible', 'off');
    end
  end

end
```

This will create three panels colored red, green, and blue, along with three toggle buttons. The callback is handled by a [nested function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html). Pushing a button will display the corresponding colored panel by turning on its visibility while turning off the visibility of all other panels.

[image]

Although this is a programmatic example, it should be straightforward to adapt it to a GUIDE-designed GUI.

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for thanks for the help